# How to go to URL once button bitmap img on Flash is clicked - Action Script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Good day.

I have little usage of Flash CS4, however i have to build a small animation.

It as six different bitmap images, each one with a effect on rollover.

However i want to each one of them to open a URL in a new Tab/Window when clicked.

And if someone know how to load each one of those URLs from a textfile.

I would be very thank full.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is

```
navigateToURL(request:URLRequest, "_blank"):void
```

"_blank" specifies a new window.

You want to load them from a textfile, but this is just not possible from Flash because Flash does not allow disk access.

Unless you mean the textfile is hosted on a server.

EDIT: Here is a comprehensive overview of loading external data into Flash: [Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html)

```
var data:Object;

// Load the external file at startup. 
// Variables will be loaded and can be referenced directly.
// The request by default can only call files on the server hosting the Flash.
private function onInitializationComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("externalFile.txt");
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
    loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderFormat.VARIABLES; // Change to .TEXT if you want to parse it yourself.
    loader.load(request);
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
     data = event.target.data;
}    

private function onClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var bitmapName:String = (event.target as Sprite).name; // Get the name of the bitmap clicked.
    var URL:String = data[bitmapName]; // A variable with bitmapName should have been loaded from the text file, so I am calling it by name.
    var openMethod:String = data[bitmapName + "Method"];

    navigateToURL(URL, openMethod);
}
```

Text file should contain data like this:

```
bitmap1=www.google.com&bitmap1Method=_blank&bitmap2=www.amazon.com&bitmap2Method=_self
```

If you want to

Comment: Yes it is to load from the hosting server.

Comment: Just for wondering. Its possible to load the value "_blank" or "_self" from the hosted text file as well ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking forward to know how its done. Thanks for the help.